# NUnit: [SetUp] in base class and [OneTimeSetup] in Dervied [TestFixture]

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, nunit, nunit-3.0

I'm looking at some test code using NUnit, which inherits from a base class containing a [SetUp] attribute:

```
public class BaseClass
{
   [SetUp]
   public void SetUp()
   {
     //do something
   }

}

[TestFixture]
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
  [OneTimeSetUp]
  public void OneTimeSetUp()
  {

   //do something here only once for the tests in this fixture but after BaseClass [Setup] method execution. 
  }
   //tests run down here.
   //[Test]
   //[Test]
   //etc
}
```

[OneTimeSetup] method is called before Base Class [Setup] method. Is there any possibility of calling if after the Base Class[Setup] method. I would the Base Class [Setup] method to be executed first and then [OneTimeSetup] method to be called only once for all the tests in the derived [TestFixture] class. [Setup] method to be executed once before every test in the [TestFixture] class. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

When you use inheritance, that means the relationship between the derived class and the base class is one of `is a`, i.e. an instance of derived class **is a** base class. For practical purposes, they are all one thing. If you don't want that to happen, then don't use inheritance.

In this case, you are running tests on DerivedClass. It gets some methods from class itself and inherits others. By using inheritance you are able to control the order of execution of methods marked with the **same** attribute. For example, a SetUp method in the base class would run before the SetUp method in the derived class.

However, methods marked by each **different** attribute run at the time they are supposed to run. OneTimeSetUp runs once before executing the tests in the class. SetUp runs before each individual test.

It's not completely clear what you are trying to accomplish here but if you want something to be done **once** after the first SetUp is called, then you could use a SetUp method in the derived class with a static flag used to cause it to execute only once.

That said, if you explain what you are trying to accomplish, there might be a cleaner way to do it.

Comment: Thanks a lot Charlie for the detailed response. BaseClass Setup method is creating the Selenium WebDriver instance, initializing the NLog and Extent Reports. I would like to run it once before every test in the derived Test Class fixture. Whereas inside the derived test class fixture, I would like to run the shared initial test steps to run once for all the tests inside that derived test class fixture. I hope it's clear what I would like to accomplish. Thanks

Comment: Using static SetUp method in the derived class, I won't be able to access base class non-static members that I will be needing.

Comment: @melleck I didn't suggest a static method at all. Rather a static  flag to be referenced by your method. I'll edit my answer with an example.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want to do in the derived fixture one-time setup?

Comment: common test steps for test methods in the derived fixture such as: 1. Login to Application with a User. 2. Go to Settings. 3. Go to Users. Then, in the test methods using the same selenium driver session. 1. Add New User. 2. Fill User Form. 3. Submit User Form. 4. Validate User created Successfully. Repeat test steps 1-4 to create multiple users using TestCaseSource.

Comment: Derived Class Setup Code : https://pasteboard.co/JyPEerU.png Derived Class Test Method Code: https://pasteboard.co/JyPEMVk.png Currently, I am managing one time setup run for the fixture using a bool variable. I just want to know if there is a better way to handle it.